# remove duplicate lines in a txt document and keep one?

Tags: perl, duplicates

i am not programmer, but i would like some help to remove duplicate lines in a document and keep only original lines.
i was trying to do this with some text processors, editpadpro, but since my file is more than 1 gigabyte, always gets frozen and can't complete the operation.

i know perl is very good at this, but i don't know how to use it, keeping in mind that the file can be over 1 or 2 gB.

example of input lines:

```
line 1 
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 1
```

example of output lines:

```
line 1 
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

i am sorry if this is very basic, but i really don't know how to proceed, most of the time i use built in functions, i hope not to annoy anyone with this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841024/using-windows-dos-shell-batch-commands-how-do-i-take-a-file-and-only-keep-uniqu but I am not sure huge files can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the lines not being in the original order, you can use this command:

```
$ sort -u old_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

The `sort` will sort your file, and the `-u` option stands for *unique* which means that it will only output the first matching line.

Even with very large files, `sort` may be your best hope.

Comment: ah ok, thanks , i run it on terminal on linux and it works, first i thought it didn't but i open system monitor and was working. thanks a lot, my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving the existing order (first time each line is found):

```
perl -i -wlne'our %uniq; $uniq{$_}++ or print' file.txt
```

Comment: is file.txt the name of my input text?

Comment: yes, it is the name of your input text (and the file will be modified unless you remove -i)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done effectively using `awk`: http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkTips

```
awk '!a[$0]++'
```