# Skip duplicate lines when downloading text file from SFTP server with WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

Is there a command for a WinSCP batch file to only append non duplicate values in the remote file to the local file?

This is my batch command:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Users\U37615\Documents\POCLOSEBATCHLOG\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open xxxxxx -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx....""" ^
    "get -append -delete xxxxxx"" ""xxxxxxx""" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

pause
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

I have a text file on the remote server that I want to append to the local file, but I want to only append items not already on the local list. Any ideas on a command or work around to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely not. This is such a custom requirement, that you cannot reasonably expect any SFTP client to support it out of the box.

---

Download the remote file (no `-append`) to a temporary local file (`temp.txt`).

And then do something like:

```
powershell -Command "type local.txt, temp.txt | sort -unique > combined.txt"
```

Some references:

- [Using windows/dos shell/batch commands, how do I take a file and only keep unique lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12841024/850848)
- [How do I concatenate two text files in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8749929/850848)