# Is it possible to delete every n lines in a text file using command prompt?

Tags: command-prompt

I have a .txt file containing roughly 25 million lines of text. I only need every 4320th line as the rest are just repeats. Is there a way to quickly do this using the program Command Prompt?

edit: This is in windows

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to quickly do it using .BAT file scripting for Windows-based systems.  What problems are you having with your attempt, specifically though?  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: This seems quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841024/using-windows-dos-shell-batch-commands-how-do-i-take-a-file-and-only-keep-uniqu